# Pull negative battery to ground with MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, batteries, negative, body-diode

I have an input signal that goes from +10 V to ground and I want use it to pull the node "A" to ground.

[image]

The current will flow towards node "A" I was thinking using a NMOS, with in mind the direction of the body diode, I would connect source to node "A", drain to ground and resistor between gate and source. But I am not sure how to drive the gate with the input signal. Any ideas?

Comment: What are you trying to do? you need to pull to ground a -9V signal, more or less. Why not use a P channel, it would be easier.

Comment: Hi @LorenzoMarcantonio, in the real world R1 is a load that the battery V1 sees. The battery is connected as input to a regulator. I cannot change the connection between battery and load, I have only available the point A as a way to close the circuit and create current flow. How would you connect the pmos?

Comment: in the 'usual' pmos way, drain to the load and source to ground (which is positive respecto to the drain, so the mos works fine). You'll need some negative voltage to drive the gate but a charge pump (or your -9V if available) would be fine